# What is the same function in postgres as mongoose middleware?

Tags: postgresql

Here is the link about mongoose middleware: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

My case is I want to update some fields after a SQL query from database when client user send request to call my api. And the fields which need to be updated is based on `Date`, so they will be updated frequently.

Update these fields in the initialization of my application is not enough.

With mongoose, I can use below way:

```js
schema.post('findOne', function(doc, next) {
  const doc = updateFields(doc);
  doc
    .save()
    .then(() => next())
    .catch(next);
})
```

How can I do this using `postgresql`?

I find a way but it seems duplicated.

The way is using `UPDATE` and `RETURNING`. But I have to write this SQL everywhere.

Or, I can encapsulate a method and call it firstly when need update the fields? I think it's duplicated either.

So, what's the best way for my case? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design correctly your [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) (and be sure to have appropriate [database indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index), and be aware of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)). Then *explicit* the set of SQL requests your application should make.

You might be interested by [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/triggers.html) (which looks similar to what you call "middleware")

Most of the requests would be in prepared statements, using [PQprepare](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-exec.html) in the initialization of your application.

Be aware that MongoDB is a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database, but [PostGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) is a [relational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) database, so they require different mindsets and approaches and should be used differently.